# Is there a way to overlay another color on top of background color in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to add `rgba(0,0,0,0.25)` on top of `backgroundColor: "#0075FF"` to make it darker. However is there any way to achieve it without using a mixed color value? Note: I also would like to avoid an approach that has an overlaid element on top of it.

Comment: why don't you just use rgba value for background instead?!, and pls tag only the related technology, for example here should be only css tagged, why React  and JS?!

Comment: Isn't adding something on top of something else exactly what an overlay is?

Comment: Why don't you just use a color picker to pick a darker color?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I meant visually. I am wondering if it is possible to use multiple backgroundColor props in one element or something similar

Comment: @imvain2 It is not an option for me

Comment: There is no need to use two elements, you can use the one line trick i described in the answer

Comment: Overlay a same-stop gradient on your background color (`background-color: #0075ff;`) with `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25), rgba(0,0,0,0.25));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a this trick with linear gradients:

```
background: linear-gradient(#f005, #f005), linear-gradient(#0f05, #0f05);
```

In this way you are using two gradients with alpha. The trick is that the colours of gradients starts and ends with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a pure CSS approach, although it sort of overlays a pseudo-element on top of the main element.

*Try hovering over the example.

```css
.colored {
  background: #0075FF;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.colored:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="colored"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always make a separate container, place the elements in it, then in css make the new container the same size as the one you want to place on the other. I used a low opacity so you can see through the top color, making it look purple when it isn't.
You gain adjust the size of the container and then use placement methods as you wish.

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  }
  
  .img {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: .5;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="img"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `:before` pseudo element.

```
<div className="container">
    ....content
</div> 

.container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0075FF;
}

.container:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```